# Python regular expression with string in it

Tags: python, regex

I would like to match a string with something like:

```
re.match(r'<some_match_symbols><my_match><some_other_match_symbols>', mystring)
```

where mymatch is a string I would like it to find. The problem is that it may be different from time to time, and it is stored in a variable. Would it be possible to add one variable to a regex?

Comment: Yes, before you compile it the regexp is just a regular string. so `re.compile(constant_stuff+varying_stuff+more_constant_stuff)` works fine.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for string concatenation: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing prevents you from simply doing this:

```
re.match('<some_match_symbols>' + '<my_match>' + '<some_other_match_symbols>', mystring)
```

Regular expressions are nothing else than a string containing some special characters, specific to the regular expression syntax. But they are still strings, so you can do whatever you are used to do with strings.

The `r'…'` syntax is btw. a raw string syntax which basically just prevents any escape sequences inside the string from being evaluated. So `r'\n'` will be the same as `'\\n'`, a string containing a backslash and an `n`; while `'\n'` contain a line break.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
url = "www.dupe.com"
expression = re.compile('<p>%s</p>'%url)
result = expression.match("<p>www.dupe.com</p>BBB")
if result:
  print result.start(), result.end()
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with this, but just a small note on the variable naming (I suspect “mather” should have been “matcher”?): `re.compile` does not return a matcher as other languages do, but returns simply a compiled regular expression, that is completely reusable and independent from the text it operates on. You can do other things on that expression other than matching (replacing is fine too), so `expression` or `urlExpression` in this case might be more appropriate :)

Comment: Yeah, that’s what I meant to say :)

Answer (score -1):

The `r''` notation is for constants.  Use the `re` library to compile from variables.

Comment: *"The `r''` notation is for constants."*: Uh? There ain't no constants in Python. `r'...'` just denotes a raw string (i.e. each character is treated literally).

Comment: @FelixKling -- are you saying I can change the value of, say, 3?

Comment: No, because `3` is a number literal. `r'...'` is a raw string literal. Literals denote values that don't have to be computed during runtime. They cannot be on the RHS of an assignment, so you cannot change them. Neither of them is a constant though. No one prevents you from assigning the string to a variable and passing that variable to `re.match`.

Comment: @FelixKling -- is a "literal" not constant?  *Can* I change the value of constants?  Of literals?

Comment: Well, I'd say the word "constant" typically refers to a symbol whose value cannot be changed after the first assignment (and no, a literal is not a symbol). For example, in PHP, `const PI = 3.14159;` is a constant. I can use `PI` anywhere but I cannot change its value. But apart from arguing about terminology, the remainder of your answer is not correct either. You don't need any specific method from the `re` module to use variables with `re.match`. You simply substitue the literal with a variable, like so: `foo = r'symbols'; re.match(foo, ...)`.

Comment: `'foo'` is just as constant as `r'bar'` or `42`. That doesn’t change the fact that the first two are both *string literals*, and as such *strings*, while the latter is a number literal, in this case an *int*. The constant-ness of things has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: @FelixKling -- ah, by "constant", you are referring to a *named constant* (or the oxymoronic *constant variable*).  Yes, Python doesn't have one.  I thought the OP was somehow trying to inject variables into a literal declaration.